# Did i reached the limits of wordpress and woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I know the question sounds a little weird, but, please, read along. I have a store based on wordpress, woocommerce and wpml - currently in two languages but with plans to add another 3. The theme is quite huge with a lot of custom integration like Infusionsoft, Xero and more. About 50 plugins, 1100 product and 1700 posts. The number of posts and products will most likely double in the near future once we add another 3 languages. The overall setup is already kind of slow although we have enough server resources: 12 cores and 31 GB of ram. On top of this, I'm looking to integrate some sort of multi store and multi domain functionality. The multi store functionality will also require to be multilingual (wpml). There are two solutions to create the multi store functionality and none of them seems to be ideal and easily replicable without hacking more into woocommerce and wordpress. 
1. Another install of wp, woocommerce, wpml and then using the woocommerce API to transfer the orders, stock, etc. back to the main site. 
2. Wordpress multisite - from what i read is quite buggy with woocommerce and wpml.

As a developer myself, I feel this is a overkill for the wp, woocommerce and wpml. Especially if we take into consideration that Opencart or Prestashop comes with this functionality by default - without any kind of complications. But maybe, just maybe I am missing something really clever. Did anyone faced a similar setup ? What are your thoughts about developing such a complex setup in Wordpress and Woocommerce? Do you guys think it's imminent to move to another solution like Opencart, Prestashop or Magento ?

I would really appreciate your feedback about this!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What i would do here is investigate why the website is slow first before adding hardware to the issue. Wordpress is a great base to start with but the same as all db driven websites needs optimization as the website grows.

There are many techniques for the below so ill just point to ideas and you can re-search them yourself and decide whether they suit your website.

**Test here:**
http://www.webpagetest.org/

**To test your server code:**

Use something like microtime to measure processes especially wp queries. http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Where possible use caching (server caching) - possibly use varnish to cache product pages and serve static pages in place of dynamically created pages.

For expensive queries like post-archives use wp-transients or your own object caching.

**To test browser code:**

This is probably where you will see the greatest timesavings if you have 50 plugins. Unfortunately dev's love to hook js files, css files to the footer/header. This can be a significant load time. Investigate what you can remove from your templates (un-used js scripts, css files, etc) and de-queue them. For more savings see if you can isolate the css / js actually needed for the page out of the files present - combine into 1 file of each. Most of the time you will need the header/ sidebar css and some text styles but you are loading an entire themes stylesheet.

**Pretty essential:** 
investigate your browser caching strategy. 
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching

**Fun project:**
Did you know you can load images/js/css to the cache using js? Pre-loading!

Maybe look at post-archives that require a lot of images and see if you can preload the "above the fold" content - your user will get a pretty quick browser load time and by the time they navigate below the fold the next batch of images should be cached (if you are combining with lazy load techniques)

This might save you the need to use extra servers but if you have to look at sharding rather than using a api to transfer data using php (i presume woo commerce api uses?)